# Why does this same algorithm produce completely different results in python and rust?

Tags: python, rust

I've correctly completed [problem 53](https://projecteuler.net/problem=53) from the project euler site in python.

```
from math import factorial

count = 0

for n in range(1, 101):

    for r in range(0, n+1):
        val = factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r))

        if val > 1_000_000:
            count += 1

print(count)
```

But for some reason what appears to be the exact same algorithm in rust produces an entirely different (and incorrect) answer.

```
fn factorial(num: u128) -> u128 {
    match num {
        0  => 1,
        1.. => (1..num+1).product(),
    }
}

fn main() {

    let mut count = 0;
    
    for n in 1..101{
    
        for r in 0..n+1{
            let val = factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));
    
            if val > 1_000_000 {
                count += 1;
            }

        }
    }
    println!("{}", count);

}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm sure it's something obvious missing. Whats the difference between the two algorithms?

Comment: Mind sharing what outputs you get from the different versions?

Comment: Do you know how large 100! gets? Do you know what the largest number is that a u128 can represent?

Comment: 4075 for python and 195 for rust

Comment: @luk2302 Wouldn't it overflow if the number was too large?

Comment: Yes, exactly. At which point any comparison and calculation with it becomes meaningless.

Comment: But doesn't rust check for overflows? I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: @luk2302 Ahh, you're correct. I've been compiling in release mode which skips the check. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integers in Python 3 are virtually unlimited. Whereas in Rust, you are hitting an overflow. The largest of the *standard* integer types in Rust is `u128`, but it's not large enough to represent numbers as huge as `100!`.

Answer (score 1):

The factorial function was overflowing and I didn't notice because I was compiling in release mode. Here's the fixed code for anyone else that makes the same mistake.

```
extern crate num;

use num::{bigint::BigUint, One};

fn factorial(value: u32) -> BigUint {
    (2..=value).fold(BigUint::one(), |res, n| res * n)
}
 
fn main() {

    let mut count = 0;
    let max = BigUint::parse_bytes(b"1000000", 10).unwrap();

    for n in 1..101{
    
        for r in 0..n+1{
            let val = factorial(n)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-r));
            if val > max {
                count += 1;
            }

        }
    }
    println!("{}", count);

}
```